# Python BeautifulSoup class find return None

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am writing a python program, using BeautifulSoup. I want to make a web scraper that will retrieve information about E-journals. I used BeautifulSoup to retrieve the html class but it is returning None or "[]". I am a beginner who started studying python 2 weeks ago so I don't know what to do at all... please help me.

Here is my code.

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

JAGS7_result = requests.get("https://agsjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/toc/15325415/2021/69/7")

JAGS7_soup = BeautifulSoup(JAGS7_result.text, "html.parser")

results = JAGS7_soup.find_all("div",{"class": "issue-item"})
print(results)```
````

Comment: Hey @Guun welcome to SO! can you please share what needs to be found from URL

Comment: @BhavyaParikh Hi! I want to get the list of titles, authors, pages, and abstracts from the URL. (My English is poor so maybe I misunderstood the question... Am I answering right?)

Answer (score 1):

Your http response was not successful. it received 403 not allowed response.

check,

```
print(JAGS7_result.status_code)
```

It should be 200. In your case it was 403.

Use request headers to overcome this issue.

```
h = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36'}
JAGS7_result = requests.get("https://agsjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/toc/15325415/2021/69/7", headers=h)
```

Now you get your desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `User-Agent` header during your request:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0"
}

JAGS7_result = requests.get(
    "https://agsjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/toc/15325415/2021/69/7",
    headers=headers,
)
JAGS7_soup = BeautifulSoup(JAGS7_result.text, "html.parser")

for title in JAGS7_soup.select("a > h2"):
    print(title.text)
```

Prints:

```
Cover
Issue Information
A glimmer of hope for the most vulnerable
Emergency department visits for emergent conditions among older adults during the COVID-19 pandemic
SARS-CoV-2 antibody detection in skilled nursing facility residents
VA home-based primary care interdisciplinary team structure varies with Veterans' needs, aligns with PACE regulation
Emergency visits by older adults decreased during COVID-19 but increased in the oldest old
Teaching geriatrics during the COVID-19 pandemic: Aquifer Geriatrics to the rescue
Changes in medication use among long-stay residents with dementia in Michigan during the pandemic
Reduction in respiratory viral infections among hospitalized older adults during the COVID-19 pandemic

...
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. It was very useful for my code!

Answer (score 0):

I would also advise that you use spiders and scrapy for your work in future. It a great package for scraping since beautifulsoup often can’t succeed over JavaScript websites.